# array only storing checkboxes with value 1 (not 0)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have checkboxes which change value using JavaScript and I want to store values of all checkboxes in a PHP array. But if the user changes the value of one checkbox to "0", the array created has only 2 values (1,1) instead of (1,0,1).

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox1[]" checked="checked" value="1" class="chbo">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox1[]" checked="checked" value="1" class="chbo">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox1[]" checked="checked" value="1" class="chbo">
```

PHP

```
$wer=$_POST['cbox1'];
echo implode(",",$wer);
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.chbo', function() {
this.value ^= 1;
console.log(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Only checked values are sent. Non-checked values won't appear in the POST-array.

Comment: then how can i post non-checked checkboxes with value "0"?

Comment: No, your code is working perfectly. Thankyou.

Comment: You should accept an answer.

Comment: how do i do that? i'm new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only successful (checked) controls are submitted. You need to add a hidden input with the default value before the checkbox.  Notice you need to hard code the indexes so that the hidden default matches the checkbox value:

```
<input type="hidden"   name="cbox1[0]" value="0" class="chbo">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox1[0]" value="1" class="chbo" checked="checked">
<input type="hidden"   name="cbox1[1]" value="0" class="chbo">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox1[1]" value="1" class="chbo" checked="checked">
```

So if not checked, only the hidden `cbox1[0]` with value `0` will be submitted.  If checked, then `cbox1[0]` with value `1` will overwrite the hidden input.

You won't need the JavaScript now because you can change the checkbox to value `0` but if it is not checked it won't be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked checkboxes do not exist within the POST or GET array after form submission.  To check for unchecked checkbox form elements, use a simple isset() call.

```
$wer[0]=isset($_POST['cbox1'][0]) ? $_POST['cbox1'][0]:0;
$wer[1]=isset($_POST['cbox1'][1]) ? $_POST['cbox1'][1]:0;
...
```